# Do I need to write "up" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-usage

> She was clearing (up) the debris of the world she had just destroyed.

Do I need the *up*? Why or why not?

Comment: Compare with "She was cleaning the debris..." It is not the debris which is being cleaned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this sentence *clearing* and *clearing up* both refer to *the world* and not *the debris*. Whereas you can *clear the room of the debris* it is not usual to specify either what is being removed or what it is being removed from when you *clear up*. So you could write

> She was clearing the world of the debris which she had made.
>   She was clearing the table of the dishes which she had used.
>
> She was clearing up after destroying the world.
>   She was clearing up after eating a meal.

Alternatively, if you want the *clearing* to refer to *the debris* then you  could use *clearing away* :

> She was clearing away the debris of the world which she had just destroyed.
>   She was clearing away the remains of the meal which she had just eaten.